# Generic copy-constructor with rvalue-reference members

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I'm working on a simple wrapper template class that logs when special member functions are called. These functions cannot be defaulted since they perform additional logging related tasks.

```
template <typename T>
struct logger {
    logger(T const& value) : value_(value) { /*...log...*/ }
    logger(T&& value) : value_(std::move(value)) { /*...log...*/ }
    logger(logger const& other) : value_(other.value_) { /*...log...*/ }
    logger(logger&& other) : value_(std::move(other.value_)) { /*...log...*/ }

    T value_;
};
```

Unfortunately, when the wrapped type is an *rvalue-reference* the *copy-constructor* fails to compile with the following error message:

> error: cannot bind ‘int’ lvalue to ‘int&&’

The reason is that an implicit copy constructor will behave somewhat different for an *rvalue-reference* member:

> **[class.copy 12.8/15]**
>   The implicitly-defined copy/move constructor for a non-union class `X` performs a memberwise copy/move of its bases and members. *[...]* Let `x` be either the parameter of the constructor or, for the move constructor, an xvalue referring to the parameter. Each base or non-static data member is copied/moved in the manner appropriate to its type:
>
> - if the member is an array, each element is direct-initialized with the corresponding subobject of `x`;
> - if a member m has rvalue reference type `T&&`, it is direct-initialized with `static_cast<T&&>(x.m)`;
> - otherwise, the base or member is direct-initialized with the corresponding base or member of `x`.

Which brings me to my question: how does one write a generic *copy-constructor* that behaves as an implicitly defined *copy-constructor*, even when working with *rvalue-references* as members.

For this particular case, I could add an additional specialization for *rvalue-references*. However, I'm looking for a generic solution that doesn't restrict to single members and does not introduce code duplication.

Comment: can u not do `logger(logger const& other) : value_(static_cast<T>(other.value_))`? since `T` is `int&&`

Comment: Kal: `T` is `int&&` for only one particular case, it could be a huge object in another and that would create an unnecessary copy.

Comment: What do you want to do if `T` is an rvalue reference? You don't have value semantics in this case. The move ctor should probably be disabled for this case, too, to avoid lifetime issues.

Comment: @DyP: I want to do the same that an implicit copy-constructor would do. That is, propagate the reference.

Comment: For an rvalue ref data member, the default implicit copy ctor is deleted.

Comment: @DyP: The snippet of the standard defining implicit copy constructors has been part of my question since I made it.

Comment: That was meant more as a warning; the Standard defines this ctor as deleted for a good reason. If you still want to force its existence and behaviour *as if* the copy-ctor was a move-ctor (for the rvalue ref member), you could try `logger(logger const& other) : value_((T)other.value_)`. This should do the necessary `static_cast` followed by a `const_cast` if `T` is an rvalue ref type.

Comment: @DyP: Your suggestion for a _C-style_ cast introduces a copy that should not be there, besides... well, being a _C-style_ cast! If what you said is true, would you mind pointing me how does a `std::tuple` containing _rvalue-references_, as those returned from `std::forward_as_tuple`, are _copy-constructed_?

Comment: I think the passage you're quoting is from 12.8/15, not /5. Anyway, as [class.copy]/11 specifies "A defaulted copy/move constructor for a class `X` is defined as deleted if `X` has: [...] for the copy constructor, a non-static data member of rvalue reference type [...]", bullet 2 of /15 doesn't apply to copy ctors. Similarly, the copy ctor of a tuple with an rvalue-ref member is deleted. The return value of `forward_as_tuple` is an rvalue, and therefore can be moved. `(T)other.value_` does not necessarily create a copy, even if, it will probably be elided IIRC.

Comment: @DyP: You are right about it being 15. My tests for copying classes with _rvalue-references_ and tuples returned from `forward_as_tuple` work fine on every compiler I tried, but indeed your quote from the standard indicates that they shouldn't. Would you post that as an answer?

Comment: @K-ballo why would it make an unnecessary copy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here be dragons.

```
logger(logger const& other) : value_(other.value_)
```

The expression `other.value_` is an lvalue of type `T const`, e.g. `int&`, `int&&` or `int const`.

1. If `T == int&&`, you need to do a `move`, as the expression is an lvalue. The `move` is equivalent to a `static_cast<int&&>`, so you could do the `static_cast` directly as well.
2. If `T == int&`, no cast is required.
3. If `T == int`, no cast is required.

For a copy ctor defined as:

```
logger(logger const& other) : value_(static_cast<T>(other.value_)) {/*...*/}
```

Applied to the third case, this is defined as the introduction of a temporary, and could result in an additional copy/move, although I think it can&will be elided.

A solution without relying on the copy/move elision is to introduce a `weird_cast`, that yields the desired type in any case:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T, class U>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_reference<T>{}, T>::type
weird_cast(U& p)
{
    return static_cast<T>(p);
}

template<class T, class U>
typename std::enable_if<not std::is_reference<T>{}, T const&>::type
weird_cast(U const& p)
{
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    int           o = 42;
    int &        lo = o;
    int &&       ro = std::move(o);
    int const   lco = o;

    int&& r = weird_cast<int&&>(ro);
    int&  l = weird_cast<int& >(lo);
    int   d = weird_cast<int  >(lco);
}
```

This is similar to `std::forward`, but also supports "forwarding" non-reference types.

---

Where are the dragons?

[class.copy]/11 specifies:

> A defaulted copy/move constructor for a class `X` is defined as deleted if `X` has:
>
> - [...]
> - for the copy constructor, a non-static data member of rvalue reference type
> - [...]

An rvalue reference is typically bound to an xvalue or prvalue, i.e. to an expression referring to an object that is "near the end of its lifetime". As lifetime doesn't get extended through function boundaries, it would be error prone to allow such a "copying".

Comment: I only want to initialize members of type `T` from another member of the same type (but possibly different value category). No `const_cast` should be done under no condition. Also, would you mind adding your reference to 12.8/11?

Comment: @K-ballo By taking the argument as `logger const& other`, the expression `other.value_` has type `T const` (hence, the `const_cast`) and is an lvalue (hence, the `move`/`static_cast`). As I wrote in my previous comment, a non-const copy ctor allows getting rid of the `const_cast`, but even as an override doesn't provide the guarantee at first glance not to modify the argument.

Comment: I still don't understand why a `const_cast` should be needed. If `logger` is `const`, a member reference is still non-const. There is no `T& const` or `T&& const`.

Comment: @K-ballo Huh! You're right, I stand corrected. I thought this rule only applies to pointers, but not to references.

Comment: To avoid confusion for future readers, I think it is important to note that I actually have an _lvalue_ of type `int&&`, not `int&`.

Comment: @K-ballo Agreed, fixed. Maybe I'll add some more text.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a specialization for rvalue-references:

```
template<typename T>
struct logger<T&&>{
  ...
};
```

But really I don't think you want `logger::_value` to be a rvalue reference...

**Edit**

Although I feel this isn't a bad solution, as it's a GENERAL workaround for ALL rvalue references, here's another option without literal specialization:

```
template<typename TT>
struct logger{
  typedef typename rvalue_remover<TT>::value T;
  //your previous code here
};
```

Where `rvalue_remover` is something like this:

```
template<typename T>struct rvalue_remover{typedef T value;};
template<typename T>struct rvalue_remover<T&&>{typedef T value;};
```

I'm pretty sure this is already defined in c++11, but I don't have it installed here so I don't remember the name.

**Edit2**

Ah! found it! It's called `std::remove_reference<T>::type`, and declared in `#include <type_traits>`

Comment: He literally said he did not want to write a specialization, that being said I have no idea why not

Comment: I could, but as I stated in my question that is not a general answer for this problem but a workaround for just this particular case.

Comment: @cluracan: I do not wish to remove the _rvalue-reference_. I intend to keep it, and still have a _copy-constructible_ class. Having _rvalue-references_ as members is perfectly fine in certain contexts. If you are looking for an example, search for `std::forward_as_tuple()`

Comment: @K-ballo - it is extremely dangerous to keep the rvalue-reference. It will cause you bugs, as it may be destroyed without notice from another place. Even the idea of copying an rvalue reference doesn't make much sense. The whole point of an rvalue reference is that it is temporary - the whole idea is that once something is defined as rvalue-reference it is never used again so it can be destroyed at will.

Comment: @cluracan: I'm aware of the dangers, they do not apply to my use case. This wrapper is used in places where an _rvalue-reference_ would be used, so the logger does not add any danger to the situation.

Comment: `std::remove_reference<T>` is different from your `rvalue_remover` in that it will strip _lvalue-references_ as well.